# How can i stop django background task permanently which is running parallely?

Tags: python, django, background-task

I have 3-4 `django` `background_tasks` which run in parallel, and I want to stop all tasks except a single one of them. `background_task` is a built-in library in `django`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I would suggest adding a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 0):

First need to stop the process/tab that is running `python manage.py process_tasks`.

Next, delete the task you no longer need from the database - you can find this in the admin panel, then, restart the process
`python manage.py process_tasks`